# With the quantum entanglement experiment what exactly do they mean by "one particle instantaneously affects the outcome of the other"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

It sounds like if you measure the spin of one particle, the other particle immediately registers as the opposite spin without anyone touching the detector. Is this what they mean?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem I also think this video http://youtu.be/ZuvK-od647c is quite nicely made.

Comment: @gwho That's insane! I was wondering what the big deal was because I had always assumed they meant they measured both at the same time. This just made quantum physics a lot more interesting to me

Comment: This is unbelievible, just to make this as clear as day, just so I can be 100% certain you understand what I meant (I know I sound very thick at this point) Say two scientists decide to do the experiment. One scientist goes to detector A and the other to B. Scientist 1 decides to measure particle A at 8:32 pm, without Scientist 2 knowing when scientist 1 will measure it. Will Scientist two receive a measurement at 8:32 without touching the detector?

Comment: @gwho According to sofia you are wrong, since she answered in depth I am going to take her word for it.

Comment: My bad that's exactly what it sounded like famous physics speakers were saying in physics documentaries.

Comment: @gwho yeah that is why I find secondary information useless, scientists like to take an interpretation, over exaggerate the evidence for it, then preach it as fact. This is why I use this website in the first place so I can find out what the experiments actually show and judge it for myself, to see past the bullshit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask :

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ *Will Scientist 2 receive a measurement at 8:32 without touching the detector?*

The answer is **we don't know**.

We believe that in the process of measurement of entangled particles, **time has no meaning**. We believe an even more amazing thing: that, if the two measurement events are separated by a **space-like interval**, the result of the measurements is *decided upon* by both particles. None of them is the *leader*, i.e. produces the result and conveys to the other particle. Both particles decide the joint result.

Just imagine that the two labs are located in rockets in opposite movements, and that each scientist performs the measurement of his particle. Imagine also that from the point of view of a third scientist, on the Earth, both measurements are done at 8:32, Greenwich hour. The scientist in each rocket would claim the he measured first, and his measurement result was *conveyed* to the other lab.

Then, **who is right**? Which one of the measurements was *independent*, and which one just conformed itself according to the information received from the other?

On the other hand, if the measurements are separated by a **time-like interval**, we can say which measurement was the 1st one. But, *honestly speaking*, not even in this case we are sure that the 1st experiment done decided alone on the result.

Comment: Oh so it does not mean what I thought it meant. Kind of disappointed now. Thank you for your answer anyway, I could have been misled completely.

Comment: @RayKay : don't be disappointed, because the situation is even more interesting than you thought. From the point of view of each scientist, **his** particle is measured first. So, if the two particles exchange information between them, does it mean that his particle gets "signals from future"?

Comment: I am still skeptical that the measurement of one particle 'collapses' the superposition of the other particle to determine its spin. I do think that the spins are predetermined.This is my position as an axiom. I am looking into bell's inequality right now that is said to show that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "receive" a measurement? There is no faster than speed of light communication involved in case that's what you were implying. Scientist 2 will still have to measure but the outcome of the measurement will be pre-decided if Scientist 1 has already made a "space-like separated" measurement on her own spin.

To make it more precise: the results of two space-like separated spin measurements along the same direction on an entangled state of two spins will be completely (anti-)correlated.